# What is the total power consumption of a flipflop?

Tags: power, current, digital-logic, flipflop

See the [datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/5b/e5/16/ec/c7/77/49/9f/CD00002418.pdf/files/CD00002418.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00002418.pdf) of D flip-flop (74V1G79).
Here the total power calculation is given as follows,

[image]
Average operating current = Switching current + Supply current.

But if there is a load in the output side of the FF, (Assume the case of ring counter with output side also with same FF 74V1G79) then total current will be as follows,

Average operating current = Switching current + Supply current + load current.

This is my understanding. Following things need to be clarified.

1) Whether this understanding is correct or not?

2) How can I get the load current? (Checked in the datasheet, but nothing related output drive current found)

### Edit

Assume the switching frequency as 500 kHz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that \$C_{PD}\$ is charged each time the flip-flop is clocked and assume Vcc = 5 volts. Also assume that \$C_{PD}\$ is discharged at the same rate (just for convenience in this example I'm giving). Different logic configurations will have different results so I'm just giving an example.

Energy put into \$C_{PD}\$ when charged = \$C_{PD}V_{cc}^2/2\$ and this is discharged (turned to heat) by the discharge process cyclically at the operating frequency F. This then tells us the power consumed is \$FC_{PD}V_{cc}^2/2\$. If we divide power by the supply voltage \$V_{cc}\$ we get the average current lost by charging up and discharging this capacitor, \$FC_{PD}V_{cc}/2\$ .

*I note that from the blue box in the question, the dynamic average current is stated as \$FCV_{cc}\$ so maybe this can be justified elsewhere in the data sheet but, for the physics of charging and discharging a capacitor at frequency F, my answer is correct.*

> How can I get the load current?

You say in your question that the load is another identical flip-flop hence, you can perform the same maths as above to calculate average load current. I don't know what output frequency is being produced but presumably you do so. do the simple math!

If you also have a resistive load that is switched on and off then the average current for that is simple ohms law multipled by duty cycle.

\$I_{cc}\$ is listed in the data sheet on page 3.

Comment: I have edited the question with 500 kHz output frequency. In the case of resistive load of 1k, duty cycle of 50%, Output current will be = (5/1k)*0.5 = 2.5 mA. Make sense?

Comment: Correct but for a resistive load, even if the frequency was 1 Hz, the long term average current is still 2.5 mA.

Comment: Explicitly saying, there is no effect for output frequency in the case resistive loads

Comment: If you average over many cycles then frequency becomes an irrelevance to the average current. Sure it peaks at 5 mA and troughs at 0 mA but the average is 2.5 mA.